# Does CIDR Notation do away with matching IP/Subnet masks?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, ipv4

With CIDR notation, do IPs and subnet masks need to match? For example, 192.168.0.0 = 255.255.0.0? Or does CIDR do away with this entirely?

How does a network know if the host IP address is on the same network when checking?

Answer (score 1):

CIDR *notation* is just a simpler way to write the subnet mask. The value of the subnet mask is the same, and the rules for subnet masks are the same, regardless of which way you enter or display the value.

So, whether you write your subnet mask as `/16` or `255.255.0.0` or `11111111111111110000000000000000`, they all represent the same 32-bit value, and that value is used the same way no matter how you choose to display it or type it in.